# Issue with rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

am facing issue in creating rating code with jquery ui radio buttonset. its going to integrated in content management so i don't want to use ids and restrict coding limitations. I have done 90% of the job by using array but when i select from bottom to top its not working properly. can anyone help on this.
Thanks

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.rating").buttonset();
    $("div.rating").find("input[type=radio]").bind('click', function(event) {       
        var currentval = $(this).val();
         var currentKey = $(this).attr("id");    
        var len = $(".rating").find("input[type=radio]:checked").length;
        var array = [];
        var arrayKeys = [];
        $("div.rating").find("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(index)  {
            var key = $(this).attr("id");
           array[index] = $(this).val();
           arrayKeys[index] = key;           
                });
            if($("div.rating").find("input[type=radio]:checked").length > 1) {
            for(var i = 0; i<array.length-1; i++){
                if(currentval == array[i]){
                    if(arrayKeys[i] != currentKey){
                        $(this).parent().find('label').removeClass('ui-state-active');
                $('.error').text('You have already chossen rating ' + currentval).show();
                return false;
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.error').hide();
                }
            }
      } 
    });
});
</script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

```html
<div class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="ss01" name="ss" value="1">
  <label for="ss01">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="ss02" name="ss" value="2">
  <label for="ss02">2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="ss03" name="ss" value="3">
  <label for="ss03">3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="ss04" name="ss" value="4">
  <label for="ss04">4</label>
  <input type="radio" id="ss05" name="ss" value="5">
  <label for="ss05">5</label>
  <input type="radio" id="ss06" name="ss" value="6">
  <label for="ss06">6</label>
</div>
<br />
<div class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="sobv01" name="sobv" value="1">
  <label for="sobv01">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="sobv02" name="sobv" value="2">
  <label for="sobv02">2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="sobv03" name="sobv" value="3">
  <label for="sobv03">3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="sobv04" name="sobv" value="4">
  <label for="sobv04">4</label>
  <input type="radio" id="sobv05" name="sobv" value="5">
  <label for="sobv05">5</label>
  <input type="radio" id="sobv06" name="sobv" value="6">
  <label for="sobv06">6</label>
</div>
<br />
<div class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="scs01" name="scs" value="1">
  <label for="scs01">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="scs02" name="scs" value="2">
  <label for="scs02">2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="scs03" name="scs" value="3">
  <label for="scs03">3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="scs04" name="scs" value="4">
  <label for="scs04">4</label>
  <input type="radio" id="scs05" name="scs" value="5">
  <label for="scs05">5</label>
  <input type="radio" id="scs06" name="scs" value="6">
  <label for="scs06">6</label>
</div>
<br />
<div class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="roc01" name="roc" value="1">
  <label for="roc01">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="roc02" name="roc" value="2">
  <label for="roc02">2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="roc03" name="roc" value="3">
  <label for="roc03">3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="roc04" name="roc" value="4">
  <label for="roc04">4</label>
  <input type="radio" id="roc05" name="roc" value="5">
  <label for="roc05">5</label>
  <input type="radio" id="roc06" name="roc" value="6">
  <label for="roc06">6</label>
</div>
<br />
<div class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="icl01" name="icl" value="1">
  <label for="icl01">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="icl02" name="icl" value="2">
  <label for="icl02">2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="icl03" name="icl" value="3">
  <label for="icl03">3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="icl04" name="icl" value="4">
  <label for="icl04">4</label>
  <input type="radio" id="icl05" name="icl" value="5">
  <label for="icl05">5</label>
  <input type="radio" id="icl06" name="icl" value="6">
  <label for="icl06">6</label>
</div>
<br />
<div class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="nlg01" name="nlg" value="1">
  <label for="nlg01">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="nlg02" name="nlg" value="2">
  <label for="nlg02">2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="nlg03" name="nlg" value="3">
  <label for="nlg03">3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="nlg04" name="nlg" value="4">
  <label for="nlg04">4</label>
  <input type="radio" id="nlg05" name="nlg" value="5">
  <label for="nlg05">5</label>
  <input type="radio" id="nlg06" name="nlg" value="6">
  <label for="nlg06">6</label>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="error"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate clearly what was the problem!
I run this snippet its working fine here.

Comment: Testing here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ma1k1z2L/

Comment: Awesome... but how can we restrict that selection of already selected value on click and not allow user to go further

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you are creating arrays based on the `id` versus the `name`. Your code should work better using `name` as your keys. I felt it would be better off using an Object.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ma1k1z2L/3/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create object to store selected values
  var selected = {};
  // Populate keys to initialize the object
  $(".rating input[type='radio']").each(function() {
    selected[$(this).attr("name")] = null;
  });
  $(".rating").buttonset();
  $(".rating input[type='radio']").on('click', function() {
    // Hide any previous errors
    $(".error").text("").hide();
    // Collect current index and value from selection
    var ci = $(this).attr("name");
    var cv = parseInt($(this).val());
    // Update the object
    selected[ci] = cv;
    // Check all elements of the object to see if this value already exists
    $.each(selected, function(key, val) {
      // Skip current index
      if (key != ci) {
        if (val == cv) {
          // We have a match, remove currently selected and present error
          // Unhighlight selected
          $(this).parent().find('label').removeClass('ui-state-active');
          // Reset value
          selected[ci] = null;
          // Show error
          $('.error').text('You have already choosen rating ' + cv).show();
        } else {
          // Do nothing
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Skipping the one we just selected, we check all the other elements to see if that value has already been selected. So if the user starts with the first  or the last or somewhere in the middle, it will not matter what they select next, it checks the whole group of selected elements to ensure that they have not selected the same value.

Comment: Awesome... but how can we restrict that selection of already selected value on click and not allow user to go further